# Crackling/Popping audio, high DPC Latency from Intel Rapid Storage Technology -drivers

Tags: windows-7, audio, ssd, noise, ahci

I'm sorry if this landed on the wrong stack, I'm not entirely sure if this or serverfault would be more suitable.

I have a very strange problem, when I install any iRST driver newest or older ones my DPC Latency goes through the roof and as a result all my audio is crackling and popping, whenever some sound is playing.

My PC:

- Windows 7 64-bit SP1
- P67 Extreme4
- Vertex 3 120GB
- i5-2500K
- Asus GTX 570 DIRECTCU II
- Corsair 750W AXEU

I've done a complete reinstall of windows and tested with only the iRST drivers installed (10.1.0.1008)

My second (resulting) problem is, that without the iRST drivers my boot takes about 9mins and shutdown takes a few mins too.

With the iRST I have a normal 45sec boot up.

**Edit:**
I should mention that the whole thing is brand new

**Edit2: **
I've noticed some problem with my USB ports too. Not sure if it is related. It takes really long times for windows to load my USB devices, be it mouse or keyboard or HDD. In BIOS the jeyboard and mouse are recognised instantly. I've ran speed test on my USB HDD's and it reports ~33Mb/s so the ports shouldn't be malfunctioning.

Comment: Do all the capacitors in the system look healthy?

Comment: Hmm, good question. I need to check on that, but I'm pretty sure there should be other problems if the caps were damaged.

Comment: hard to say. Busted caps can cause really weird problems. Especially since they can still function somewhat. And parameters like heat can begin to factor in more. I wouldn't rule them out without a visual inspection.

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll check them. Would be just my luck that a totally new Mobo had busted caps :D

Comment: Well, thing about new hardware is that it may have a defect and thus was prone to fail very quickly. I figure after a few months of solid operation, you can rule out a manufacturing defect, in general.

Comment: I tried checking all the caps, but they seem to be a newer model, which doesn't have the easy to spot bulging-top-when-broken. There seemed not to be any leakage from the caps either, though I didn't disassemble the comp to check this thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but have you gotten a resolution? There have been a lot of releases of the Intel Rapid Storage Technology drivers since 10.1... so definitely try updating to the latest version.

[10.8.0.1003](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20624&ProdId=2101&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%207%20(64-bit)*&DownloadType=Drivers)

Comment: Ah, very nice. No I haven't found a resolution. But I will try the newest RST tonight :)

Comment: Turns out that the new version is having the same problem. I'm really leaning towards some kind of hardware fault.

Answer (score 0):

Wow this goes back this far!

I have a Z370 and 8700K. I get random audio stutters and found out it was caused by me updating my Intel RST driver to the latest version. I rolled back to the version on my motherboards support page (version 17.7.0.1006) and the stutters went away completely. That was a year or two ago.

I tried again to use the latest RST drivers for intel 8th gen series from Intel's site. Which have even been recently updated. Same thing, random audio stutters. A day or two can go by without a stutter but they do happen. Once again rolling back to the 17.7 version removes them completely.

Found someone else on reddit trying to track down why they were having audio stutters. They used LatencyMon and saw it was Intel RST driver as well and installed the version I used and it was fixed for them.